# How lo load data from mysql database more quickly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html search form which is like bellow image :

[image]

In this search form I need to **search data from 7 tables**. In this 7 tables there are more than 11K data stored. So that I am using following sql `JOIN` query to get the result.

But it's taking loooong time to get the result (sometime showing error message) if for e.g. I search for **Family Name = s**. I mean if there are huge data in the table columns.  How can solve this issue ? I used `LIMIT` but I think it's not helpful in this query because first I have to search to all 7 tables !

**Sql Query:**

```
$getSearch .= " cd.cdid, cd.family_name, cd.given_name, cd.department, cd.title, company.cid, company.company_name, users.nickname, contact_label.label_data  FROM
            contact_details as cd
            LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = cd.user_id
            LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
            LEFT JOIN contact_docs ON contact_docs.cdid = cd.cdid
            LEFT JOIN userkeywords ON userkeywords . cdid = cd . cdid
            LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords . kid = userkeywords . kid
            LEFT JOIN contact_label ON contact_label.cdid = cd.cdid
            WHERE 1=1 ";


    if(!empty($ad_company)){
        $getSearch .= "AND company.company_name LIKE '$ad_company%' ";
    }
    if(!empty($ad_fname)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.family_name LIKE '$ad_fname%' ";
    }
    if(!empty($ad_department)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.department LIKE '$ad_department%' ";
    }

    if(!empty($ad_mp)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.mp >= '$ad_mp' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_e2)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.e2 >= '$ad_e2' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_pl)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.pl >= '$ad_pl' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_ap)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.ap >= '$ad_ap' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_j2)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.j2 >= '$ad_j2' "; 
    }

    if(!empty($ad_agreater)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.age >= '$ad_agreater' ";  
    }
    if(!empty($ad_aless)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.age <= '$ad_aless' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_agreater) && !empty($ad_aless)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.age BETWEEN '$ad_agreater' AND '$ad_aless'";  
    }


    if(!empty($ad_sgreater)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.comp >= '$ad_sgreater' "; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_sless)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.comp <= '$ad_sless' ";    
    }
    if(!empty($ad_sgreater) && !empty($ad_sless)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.comp BETWEEN '$ad_sgreater' AND '$ad_sless'"; 
    }


    if(!empty($ad_noteterm)){    
        $ad_noteterm = preg_replace("/\{ASUSIBBIR\}(.+?)\s:\s(.+?)\{ASUSIBBIR\}/m", "$2", $ad_noteterm);
        $getSearch .= "AND LOCATE('$ad_noteterm', REPLACE (notesUpdate, '{ASUSIBBIR}', ' '))";
    }

    if(!empty($ad_cnote)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND LOCATE('$ad_cnote', cd.characterNotes)"; 
    }
    if(!empty($ad_twork)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND contact_label.label_data LIKE '%$ad_twork%'";    
    }
    if(!empty($ad_tmobile)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.mobile_phone like '%$ad_tmobile%'";   
    }

    if(!empty($ad_resume)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND LOCATE('$ad_resume', contact_docs.file_content)";    //is this the resume? yes
    }

    if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && empty($ad_dateto)){    
            $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom'AND '$date'";  
    }

    if(!empty($ad_dateto) && empty($ad_datefrom)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN date('0000-00-00') AND '$ad_dateto' "; 
    }

    if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && !empty($ad_dateto)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$ad_dateto'";    
    }

    if(!empty($ad_type)){    
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.type = '$ad_type' ";  
    }

    if(!empty($ad_wemail)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.email LIKE '$ad_wemail%'";    
    }

    if(!empty($ad_pemail)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.email_private LIKE '$ad_pemail%'";    
    }

    if(!empty($ad_title)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.title LIKE '$ad_title%'"; 
    }

    if(!empty($ad_source)){
        $getSearch .= "AND cd.source LIKE '$ad_source%'";   
    }


    if(!empty($ad_consultant)){
        $getSearch .= "AND users.nickname LIKE '%$ad_consultant%'"; 
    }

    if(!empty($ad_keyword)){
        $ad_keyword_param = str_replace(",","','",$ad_keyword);
        $getSearch .= " AND keywords.keywordName IN ('$ad_keyword_param') ";
    }

    $getSearch .= " GROUP BY cd.user_id, cd.cid, cd.cdid ";

    if(!empty($ad_keyword)){
        $ad_keyword_param = str_replace(",",",",$ad_keyword);
        $getSearch .= " ) as a WHERE keywordName LIKE '$ad_keyword_param%' ";
    }

    $f = microtime(true);
    //$getSearch .= "ORDER BY cd.given_name ASC";
    $getSearch .= "ORDER BY cd.given_name DESC LIMIT 10";
    $getSearch =  mysqli_query($link, $getSearch);
```

Comment: You seriously need to normalize your database.

Comment: Yes I think so but do you have any idea ?

Comment: Also why are you using `where 1=1`?

Comment: You are not selecting anything from the keywords tables, why are they in the query?

Comment: Yes I am getting keywords from keywords tables.

Comment: You are going to end up searching EVERYTHING in the keywords table, and every other table, since you have no exclusions for them with your current query. Even if you had indexes it wouldn't matter. You don't have any exclusions. Further more, Where 1 = 1 is going to do the same thing I just said above. Move through every row on every table needlessly.

Comment: @V_RocKs so what's the solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is normalize your database, MySQL has good support for joins but as you have experienced it has several fallbacks when using more than three joins, therefore doing a re-design of you database is my first recommendation.

Other alternatives are to use stored procedures or views, that should work faster.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping all joins are necessary, this is a huge query and this will take long and its normal. Hope you have all the needed indexes.

First check for **index misses**. **Try this in a stored procedure**, because in dynamic query run DB drivers on the server-side have to parse, analyze, plan, and optimize every time the query statement is called. It is far more efficient to have the procedure stored on the server, where the DB engine can pre-compile and analyze the procedure once, then commit it to cache and run it directly.

Even after all above don't work, there are 2 options.

**1. Increasing the PHP time limit**

Either editing the php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 500
```

Or a method call

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
```

**2. Redesigning the query**

With all these joins its obvious the query is slow. You need to either **de-normalize the table** (if you are ok with redundant data) or you have to think do you need all these information in the first page.

Ex: cd.cdid, cd.family_name, cd.given_name, cd.department, cd.title, company.cid can be shown in the list page and you can show other details when user hovers/click on a result (lazy loading the feather information)

However as you are searching with all the columns it might be not possible.

Comment: Basically all data is coming from only 1 table which is company_details as cd but I am searching to all 7 tables.

Comment: Ok, I get it, Seems like you need to go with either de-normalize table. Or try the stored procedure

Comment: okey. I am using mysqli to other pages. Is there any problem If I use stored procedure only for this search page ? and if possible can you show me with my given query ?

Comment: When the query is too large you can move to sp (stored procedure), Is this a website or a Enterprise level application ?
If you want to use sp check the following tutorials:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Comment: Enterprise Level Application.

Comment: In that case you have to go with the agreed practices in the company. Some only use SP, some dont use SP at all. So what is your process. decision if you can use a SP for only that page depends on the engineering practice you use. However from my view i dont see any issue if you use SP only when needed.

Comment: Thanks @Malinga for all suggestions :)

Comment: np, Hope i answered you

Comment: @shibbirahmed: If you feel this answer is correct, Mark it as correct pls

Answer (score 0):

You have to make indexes each queries.
If you search 'First Name', that script makes query like this.

```
select cd.cdid, cd.family_name, cd.given_name, cd.department, cd.title, company.cid, company.company_name, users.nickname, contact_label.label_data  FROM
        contact_details as cd
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = cd.user_id
        LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
        LEFT JOIN contact_docs ON contact_docs.cdid = cd.cdid
        LEFT JOIN userkeywords ON userkeywords . cdid = cd . cdid
        LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords . kid = userkeywords . kid
        LEFT JOIN contact_label ON contact_label.cdid = cd.cdid
        WHERE 1=1 AND cd.family_name LIKE 'SEARCH_WORD%'
```

Mysql must have indexes.

```
users table : indexed column = user_id (Maybe PK?)
company table : indexed column = cid (Maybe PK?)
contact_docs table : indexed column = cdid (Maybe PK?)
userkeywords table : indexed column = cdid (Maybe PK?)
keywords table : indexed column = kid (Maybe PK?)
contact_label table : indexed column = cdid (Maybe PK?)
contact_details table : indexed column = family_name, cid(Maybe PK?), cdid
```

And, You must verify that SQL using by [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).